# EmberJS - one way binding of query param to input field value broken

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In below example:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  queryParams: ['query'],
  query: null,

  queryField: Ember.computed.oneWay('query'),
  actions: {
    search: function() {
      this.set('query', this.get('queryField'));
    }
  }
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  queryParams: {
    query: {
      // Opt into full transition
      refreshModel: true
    }
  } 
});
```

Running example: http://jsbin.com/tukoye/2#/?query=22345

... if we arrive at ...?query=22345, any subsequent address navigation that changes query param will also update input field value. However after executing first search, this binding is broken, and field value no longer updates when query param changes.

**Isn't the whole idea of :
    queryField: Ember.computed.oneWay('query')
to always update queryField property?**

(jsBin code here: http://jsbin.com/tukoye/edit?html,js)

One possible solution would be to add this to route:

```
actions: {
        queryParamsDidChange: function(params) {
            this.controllerFor('application').set('queryField', params.query);
        }
    }
```

... and remove `queryField: Ember.computed.oneWay('query')` from controller.

**I'm looking for a best practice approach.**

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind `Ember.computed.oneWay` is that you've got one way binding provided. So after you change the `queryField` to something else (just editing the input), it will be overridden.

What you can do instead is to create an observer that updates your queryField with some latency, e.g. using `Ember.run.debounce`.

Comment: it seems a lot of hassle for such a standard functionality, perhaps there's a more straight forward way?

Comment: I've added solution with use of queryParamsDidChange to my question, what do you think of that?